# login flow api server python

Tags: python, api

Im kind fo new in this so any help will be highly appreciated.

Im trying to write an API server that will contain simple request of user login.

This is what i got so far, hashing:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, Response
import jwt

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
if "user" not in request.json \
        or "password" not in request.json:
    return Response(
        "missing credentials",
        status=400,)
user = request.json["user"]
password = request.json["password"]
encoded_jwt = jwt.encode({"sub": user}, "secret", algorithm="HS256")
return jsonify({"token": encoded_jwt})

app.run()
```

Assuming i have a dict of users and passwords for example:

USER_DICT = {"user":"ben", "password":"12345"}.

I want to write a code that receive the user name and password, hash it, and then verify if the password and user name is correct (by using the dict).

1. should i save hashed password in the dict? if so how?

I hope I was able to explain myself well.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I normally use `passlib` to do this when I am building rest API using `fastapi` but I am not if it works with `flask`.

**To Install**

```
pip install "passlib[bcrypt]"
Or
pip3 install "passlib[bcrypt]"
```

**Usage**

```py
from passlib.context import CryptContext

pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes='bcrypt')

"""
Call this function when creating a new 
user.

Call this function to hash the
password received from the user
"""
def hashed_pwd(password: str) -> str:
    return pwd_context.hash(password)

"""
Call this function on login attempt.

Call this function to check if the
password enter by the user is equivalent to the 
hashed password in the database
"""
def verify_pwd(user_pass: str, hashed_pass: str) -> bool:
    return pwd_context.verify(user_pass, hashed_pass)
```